# Choose query database or use ram to build listview

Tags: android, algorithm

I need to build a listview with many items.Each item info queries from managerQuery or sqlite.It has some fields: **title(String)**, **description(String)**, **path(string)**. I waver between save info of list object or get info while building each item. Saving info to list object will increase ram and  getting info while building each item makes app slow (my listview has large no. of items).

Comment: I think you can use SimpleCursorAdapter (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) and  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UsingSimpleCursorAdapterandListView.htm

Comment: Use view holder class in your base adaper of listview . http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Answer (score 1):

Querying the db every time you build new item will slow down the list scrolling. Getting data before hand is better approach.